# How to match the empty case in CUP parser grammar

Tags: java, compiler-construction, parser-generator, jflex, cup

I am using CUP to generate a parser, and I want an empty file to be an acceptable program. I have tried add the empty case to my start symbol, based off the response to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15064980/in-cup-how-to-make-something-optional-to-parse).

```
start with prog;

/* The grammar rules */
prog    ::= class_block:cb   
        |   class_block:cb stmts:sb
        |   stmts:sb
        |   // desired empty case
        ;
```

Including the desired empty case gives me the following error:

```
parser.java:516: error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Symbol
CUP$parser$result = parser.getSymbolFactory().newSymbol("prog",0, ((java_cup.runtime.Symbol)CUP$parser$stack.peek()), RESULT);
```

How can I modify my grammar so that the parser accepts an empty file?
I am using Jflex as my lexer, and ComplexSymbolFactory as the type of the symbols.

EDIT: I've confirmed that the grammar above is the correct way to include empty. However, ComplexSymbolFactory is having problems converting the empty object to a symbol. 
I get this error even when running [this example](http://www2.in.tum.de/repos/cup/develop/testgrammars/minijava2/) from the official CUP website.

Comment: Try set as optional: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15064980/in-cup-how-to-make-something-optional-to-parse

Comment: I linked to this post in my question. The solution did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the .jars from a friend github project and problem solved.

You can see it's a BUG here: https://github.com/jflex-de/jflex/issues/384

Try to downgrade the version.

Comment: Thanks! Although I can't easily test this because I got it working by upgrading Mac OS from 10.13 to 10.14.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about any bugs, but I know you can rewrite your grammar to make the empty case work.
for example:

```
Prog ::= 
   class_block:cb statement:s
   | /* the empty production */
;
```

I have tried this, and it works for empty productions. Having a production where it is a block and then a statement, or a statement, or an empty, conflicts. there isn't a way to tell during the generation for the parser at the program grammar rules which is a statement and what is an empty. Changing it only being a block and a statement, or an empty clarifies that.